# Desktop folder location

Tags: filesystem

My DESKTOP folder is NOT shown when listing (ls -la) my HOME folder, it is in/on my DOCUMENTS folder. I can still access files, launch applications without apparent problem, so I'd appreciate some help and answers to two questions:-
1) Does the DESKTOP folder have to be in/on HOME?
2) If so what is the easiest/safest way to move it there?
I'm sorry if the is basic stuff, but it is where I am.
Hall

Comment: Look in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. It designates which folders are treated as Desktop, Music, etc, by the system. If you have different system language settings, it's common for folders to be named in the locale language, and not in English `Desktop`.

Comment: Thank you Sergiy, this is part of the listing I found:-XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Documents/Desktop"
As things are working OK I think I shall leave it where it is. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably moved the folder accidentally in the Documents folder at some time. You can safely move it back to your home using Files. It will retain its special status, and automatically, your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file will be updated.

In case the folder "lost" its special status, you will need to restore its special status after moving it back to your home folder by editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to read `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop`.

Comment: Between you and Sergiy you have solved my problem, both responses are greatly appreciated, as a newbie 81 year old, I have been know to "do" things accidentally. Thank you again. Hal